# Retrieve entities and their related entities in one go

Tags: hibernate

I have some `ManyToMany` relations in my model. When I retrieve all entities from a domain, is there a way, by configuration, the retrieve the related entities in one go? I'll put an example below.

An `Aliment` may contain many `Nutrient`, and a `Nutrient` may be contained in many `Aliment`. This translates into 3 tables: `aliments`, `nutrients` and `aliments_nutrients`. The corresponding mapping would be:

```
@Entity
public class Aliment {

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "aliments_nutrients",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "aliment_id", nullable = false) },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "nutrient_id", nullable = false) })
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    private Set<Nutrient> nutrients = new HashSet<>();

}
```

When I select all `Aliment`, I end up with N subselect of `Nutrient`. I would rather have Hibernate issue three requests in that case (`* FROM aliments`, `* FROM aliments_nutrients` and `* FROM nutrients`), and have the mapping built from these. Thank you for your pointers.

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#fetching-strategies-dynamic-fetching

Comment: Oh... Of course. Thanks a lot!